# How to get info for more than 50 tracks using the albums/{id}/tracks endpoint on Spotify API

Tags: spotify

I'm using the `albums/{id}/tracks` endpoint to fetch name and the Spotify ID of all the tracks on an album. I am using curl and jq to do so:

```
curl -s "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/62VlldLNKK8OGw8vbyIFED/tracks?limit=50" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" | jq -r '.items[]| [.name, .id] | @csv'
```

However, according to the online documentation, the maximum number of tracks to return is set to 50. How can I get around this limitation and get data for tracks 51-120 on this album?

Comment: they are probably sending a `token` in the response which you have to feed to the next subsequent response to get the next set of results, basically paginate through the result set

Comment: It worked. There's a url for the next 50 results under `next.` Thanks.

Comment: yea it looks like what it returns is a basic `limit`, `offset` to paginate, just throw the request in a while loop to check if that variable is present and you should be able to get all the desired results

Comment: @HubertLéveilléGauvin, I would help if I had a test token )